# Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)

Tags: python, opencv

I get this error:
Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
when running the following code:

```
I1 = cv2.imread('library1.jpg');
I2 = cv2.imread('library2.jpg');
# Load matching points
matches = np.loadtxt('library_matches.txt');
img = np.hstack((I1, I2))
# Plot corresponding points
radius = 2
thickness = 2
for m in matches:
    # draw the keypoints
    pt1 = (int(m[0]), int(m[1]))
    pt2 = (int(m[2] + I1.shape[1]), int(m[3]))
    lineColor = cv2.cv.CV_RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ptColor = cv2.cv.CV_RGB(0, 255, 0)
    cv2.circle(img, pt1, radius, ptColor, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, lineColor, thickness)
    cv2.circle(img, pt2, radius, ptColor, thickness)
cv2.imshow("Matches", img)
```

This code is for getting corresponding features in two similar images from different views.
Any help please ??

Comment: Drawing functions seem to require a contiguous array. This can happen after you do a `np.rot90(image)` - so `np.copy` and `np.array` (constructing an array) are OK, but I prefer to use `np.ascontiguousarray()` - because it says what's going on there.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128836/7829525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

`img = np.hstack((I1, I2))`

to:

`img = np.array(np.hstack((I1, I2)))`

Comment: Iy's a good answer. The problem was with "hstack". I just replaced it with 2 lined of code. In each one I just copy each image in its position. That's much better than using "hstack".

Comment: Can you explain what the underlying issue is though? I'm running into the same error when using cv2.findContours. Its not clear from your answer what the error is actuallly saying since you only provide a solution the OPs very specific problem.

Comment: Look like something like `img = np.copy(img)` also can solve problem.