# python opencv TypeError: Layout of the output array incompatible with cv::Mat

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, opencv, numpy

I'm using the selective search here: http://koen.me/research/selectivesearch/
This gives possible regions of interest where an object might be. I want to do some processing and retain only some of the regions, and then remove duplicate bounding boxes to have a final neat collection of bounding boxes. To discard unwanted/duplicated bounding boxes regions, I'm using the `grouprectangles` function of opencv for pruning.

Once I get the interesting regions from Matlab from the "selective search algorithm" in the link above, I save the results in a `.mat` file and then retrieve them in a python program, like this:

```
 import scipy.io as sio
 inboxes = sio.loadmat('C:\\PATH_TO_MATFILE.mat')
 candidates = np.array(inboxes['boxes'])
 # candidates is 4 x N array with each row describing a bounding box like this: 
 # [rowBegin colBegin rowEnd colEnd]
 # Now I will process the candidates and retain only those regions that are interesting
 found = [] # This is the list in which I will retain what's interesting
 for win in candidates: 
     # doing some processing here, and if some condition is met, then retain it:
     found.append(win)

# Now I want to store only the interesting regions, stored in 'found', 
# and prune unnecessary bounding boxes

boxes = cv2.groupRectangles(found, 1, 2) # But I get an error here
```

The error is:

```
    boxes = cv2.groupRectangles(found, 1, 2)
TypeError: Layout of the output array rectList is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

What's wrong?
I did something very similar in another piece of code which gave no errors. This was the error-free code:

```
inboxes = sio.loadmat('C:\\PATH_TO_MY_FILE\\boxes.mat')
boxes = np.array(inboxes['boxes'])
pruned_boxes = cv2.groupRectangles(boxes.tolist(), 100, 300)
```

The only difference I can see is that `boxes` was a numpy array which I then converted to a list. But in my problematic code, `found` is already a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to convert `found` first to a numpy array, and then to recovert it into a list:

```
found = np.array(found)
boxes = cv2.groupRectangles(found.tolist(), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 86):

My own solution was simply to ask a copy of original array...(god & gary bradski knows why...)

```
im = dbimg[i]
bb = boxes[i]  
m = im.transpose((1, 2, 0)).astype(np.uint8).copy() 
pt1 = (bb[0],bb[1])
pt2 = (bb[0]+bb[2],bb[1]+bb[3])  
cv2.rectangle(m,pt1,pt2,(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: simply copying the array worked for me for a similar error as well.

Comment: Can confirm this as well, there seems to be no visible difference, tho.

Comment: This solution worked for a similar error produced by the cv2.ellipse() function

Comment: Same with cv2.line ... although it seems that the issue was solved by changing it to a np array rather than "just" making a copy of it (that is, it should be a np array copy of your list)

Comment: I had the same problem, and I noticed if I just use `astype(np.uint8)` it also just works. But then I read that `astype` automatically copies the array.

Comment: Deniz Beker’s solution(`ascontiguousarray`) explains why.

Comment: thanks! I had identical problem with `cv2.HoughLinesP` AND `cv2.line` methods, and a conversion to int through `.astype(np.uint8)` solved both issues and saved my hair!

Answer (score 61):

Another reason may be that the array is not contiguous. Making it contiguous would also solve the issue

`image = np.ascontiguousarray(image, dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: Works. Can anyone explain why this is necessary for the cv2.rectangle() function?

Comment: it's `ascontiguousarray` -> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html

Comment: @Nic worked for me too.  I'd like to hear why this is necessary too.

Comment: The error message more-or-less describes it, but yeah, it uses some specialized terms. If you want to dig more, here's the cv2 code: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L327-L336 Basically, `cv::Mat` can only express a certain type of stride (or "step"), and you need a writeable view, so you can't copy (as that defeats the purpose of an output arg entirely), hence the fail-fast. For more details: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details

Comment: Like some other people in this comment area, I also got here because of issues with `cv2.rectange()`. My problem was with the color type, my color was `np.ndarray`, converting it to `tuple` solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of proposed solutions here, but the root cause is the memory layout of the array. For some reason (edit: see comment below), OpenCV requires its input to be in C order (row-major) and not F order (column-major), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266338/what-does-the-order-parameter-in-numpy-array-do-aka-what-is-contiguous-order) for details.

All of the proposed solutions here implicitly change the array to C order:

- using `array.copy()` does it because there is a default parameter of `order='C'`
- converting to a list and back to NumPy, since C order is the default
- `array.astype()` *might* do this (seems to depend on the original layout and dtype)
- `np.ascontiguousarray()` converts to C order.

Here's a little example that reproduces the issue, with `cv2.line` in this case.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Breaks
img = np.require(img, requirements=["F_CONTIGUOUS"])

# img = np.require(img, requirements=["C_CONTIGUOUS"])  # Fixes it
# img = img.copy()  # Also fixes it

cv2.line(img, (10, 10), (100, 100), (255,0,0), 5)
```

Comment: “For some reason, OpenCV requires its input to be in C order” it’s a design decision. It makes all their code simpler. Having to deal with arbitrary memory layout requires a bit more work. OpenCV requires each image row to be contiguous in memory, it does allow a gap between rows.

Answer (score 5):

Opencv appears to have issues drawing to numpy arrays that have the data type `np.int64`, which is the default data type returned by methods such as `np.array` and `np.full`:

```
>>> canvas = np.full((256, 256, 3), 255)
>>> canvas
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]])
>>> canvas.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> cv2.rectangle(canvas, (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 0, 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

The solution is to convert the array to `np.int32` first:

```
>>> cv2.rectangle(canvas.astype(np.int32), (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 0, 0))
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem when running

> image = cv2.putText(image, 'text', org, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)

This worked for me

> image = cv2.putText(image.astype(np.uint8).copy(), 'text', org, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, it seems that many of us have used the solution of Etienne Perot above, minus `.copy()`. Converting the array type to int is enough. For example, when using the Hough transform:

```
    # Define the Hough transform parameters
    rho,theta,threshold,min,max = 1, np.pi/180, 30, 40, 60  

    image = ima.astype(np.uint8) # assuming that ima is an image.

    # Run Hough on edge detected image
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(sob, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min, max)

    # Iterate over the output "lines" and draw lines on the blank 
    line_image = np.array([[0 for col in range(x)] for row in range(y)]).astype(np.uint8)

    for line in lines: # lines are series of (x,y) coordinates
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,0), 10)
```

Only then could the data be plotted out using `plt.imshow()`