# Reinterpreting row matrices as column matrices in Eigen

Tags: numpy, eigen, pybind11

When writing Eigen code that interfaces with or binds to NumPy (via pybind11), we must deal with the change in storage order from Python's row-major default to Eigen's column-major default. While this would usually require a copy, it should be possible to do without a copy as long as we are ok with our NumPy matrix ending up as its transpose in Eigen. For example, the following C-contiguous / row-major matrix in NumPy

```
[ 1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6 ]
```

has the exact same in-memory layout as the following F-contiguous / column-major matrix in Eigen

```
[ 1, 4,
  2, 5,
  3, 6 ]
```

The question then is, given a `const Eigen::Ref<const RowMatrixXd> &cstyle` like the first example, how do we get a `MatrixXd` (or `Ref` or `Map`) that points to the same data, but now transposed and in a different storage order without any copy.

For simplicity, I'm using `using RowMatrixXd = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>` above. Also, the requirement of `const Eigen::Ref<const ...> &...` is to allow pybind11 to pass NumPy C-contiguous arrays to Eigen without a copy.

The only solution I could find seems to have trouble with the constant pointer that is generated by a call to `.data()` on a `Ref`:

```cpp
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

// Should be what we want, but run into a compile error on the const * from .data(),
// since cstyle is a Ref
Map<MatrixXd>(cstyle.data(), cstyle.cols(), cstyle.rows());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. Do you just want to use `cstyle.transpose()`? (This has zero cost). Otherwise, if you really want to create a `Map` to const data, use `Map<const MatrixXd>`.

Comment: Ya I think my problem was that I was benchmarking the `.transpose()` approach after an assignment into a `MatrixXd` type. I think that the change from `Ref` to a `MatrixXd` causes a copy, which I attributed to the transpose? Either way, both of your suggestions are correct - thank you!

Comment: From the NumPy end, Numpy supports  both C contiguous and Fortran contiguous arrays. Why not create your NumPy arrays with Fortran memory layout? See here for how to create Fortran order arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266338/what-does-the-order-parameter-in-numpy-array-do-aka-what-is-contiguous-order See here for how to convert an array to Fortran order, which is a copy if the array is C contiguous, or a no-op if the array is already in the correct order: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html

Comment: Ah it's a good suggestion, but the C-contiguous arrays that the library users are passing to these functions are already in the right memory layout. Forcing them to use Fortran-contiguous would also mean they'd have to change all their left-multiplies to right-, transpose their matrices, etc.